# ClassCastException error when using setOnScrollListener

Tags: java, android

Below is a code where data will come at scrolling time but there is an error i.e 
ClassCastException. Please help me to solve this error. Now I have added my whole fragment class Similar_Matchs_Tab where we fetching the from server.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.devbhoomimedia.maangal.ProfilesActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$OnScrollListener`

```
public class Similar_Matchs_Tab extends Fragment  {
private ListView listView;
public Similar_Matchs_Tab() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    JSON_URL = "https://www.maangal.com/maangal_mobile/similar_matches.php?matri_id="+email;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Inflate the layout for this fragment

```
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_tab, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) getActivity());
    sendRequest();
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

sendRequest function to fetch the data

```
private void sendRequest(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    showJSON(response);
                    Log.e("Similar MAtches******",response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 30000;
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
protected void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    Profile_Match_custom_List cl = new Profile_Match_custom_List(getActivity(), ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.ages, ParseJSON.heights, ParseJSON.communities,ParseJSON.castes,ParseJSON.educations,ParseJSON.occupations,ParseJSON.incomes,ParseJSON.pics,ParseJSON.locations,ParseJSON.shortlist,ParseJSON.expressinterest);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting this error is because you're trying to cast activity to a scroll listener which is not possible. So to fix the problem just set the appropriate interface and it should work. Replace `listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) getActivity());` with this:

```
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If I use this where will I put the function for fetching data

Comment: You already have it in your code, here: `listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollFinishListener(1){...}` . Just follow my instruction(answer) and leave the other codes untouched.

Comment: Same error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.devbhoomimedia.maangal.ProfilesActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$OnScrollListener

Comment: Are you sure you have removed this code: `listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) getActivity());`

Comment: No you are doing the wrong thing, its obvious that you have removed the code that was loading your data. The code i told you to replace is this `listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) getActivity());` and its still present in your code. Please reverse changes and follow my answer step by step.

Comment: Sorry sir, I have removed this from my code. And now it's working but I need also loader when we scroll down. thank you once again

Comment: I can't post much codes here, so accept this answer(since it help solved the original problem), and post that as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

B'coz you're casting Activity into AbsListView.OnScrollListener interface that's why you're getting classCastException.

just remove `listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) getActivity());`

and replace

```
listView.setOnScrollListener((ProfileActivity) getActivity());
```

Comment: When I did this it's also shows Inconvertible types

Comment: are you doing this in ProfileActivity() or anywhere else

Comment: I am doing this code on a fragment class which is Similar_Matchs

Comment: I am not understanding. I am new in android

Comment: alright no problem, just check the line class ProfileActivity extends ?????. what is there on place of '?' mark in your ProfileActivity file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159891/discussion-between-nirmal-prajapat-and-user6734679).

Answer (score 0):

change it

```
listView.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) getActivity());
```

to

```
listView.setOnScrollListener((ProfileActivity)getActivity());
```

and `ProfileActivity` must implements `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`.

Comment: When I did this it's also shows Inconvertible types

Answer (score 0):

Your  activity does not implement AbsListView.OnScrollListener interface.